I can't decrease the size of my waves in my web site
So i am bulding a website and i cant find out how to decrease the height of the waves on the html or css files. i never worked with them and i can't seem to understand them cause everytime i try lowering the height on the css the "background" of the waves disappear but the waves remain the same size.
.waves {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px; 
  margin-bottom:-7px; /*Fix for safari gap*/
  min-height:50px;
  max-height:50px;
}

.content {
  position:relative;
  height:24vh;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: white;
}

.parallax > use {
  animation: move-forever 25s cubic-bezier(.55,.5,.45,.5)     infinite;
}

.parallax > use:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-duration: 7s;
}

.parallax > use:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -3s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

.parallax > use:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
  animation-duration: 13s;
}

.parallax > use:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
  animation-duration: 20s;
}

@keyframes move-forever {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(-90px,0,0);
  }
  100% { 
    transform: translate3d(85px,0,0);
  }
}

/*Shrinking for mobile*/
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .waves {
    height:40px;
    min-height:40px;
  }

  .content {
    height:30vh;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size:24px;
  }
}

HTML CODE:
<div>
    <svg class="waves" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 24 150 28" preserveAspectRatio="none" shape-rendering="auto">
        <defs>
            <path id="gentle-wave"
                d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z" />
        </defs>
        <g class="parallax">
            <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="0" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.7" />
            <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="3" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" />
            <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="5" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)" />
            <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="7" fill="#fff" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

I tried to change the viewbox on the html file and it does not work, fixing the height and witdh on the css and well.. nothing..

Basically you set the height: 25px to the desired amount. Make sure that no other min-height or max-height collide with it.


.waves {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin-bottom: -7px;
  /*Fix for safari gap*/
  min-height: 5px;
  max-height: 5px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 24vh;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.parallax>use {
  animation: move-forever 25s cubic-bezier(.55, .5, .45, .5) infinite;
}

.parallax>use:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-duration: 7s;
}

.parallax>use:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -3s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

.parallax>use:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
  animation-duration: 13s;
}

.parallax>use:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
  animation-duration: 20s;
}

@keyframes move-forever {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(85px, 0, 0);
  }
}


/*Shrinking for mobile*/

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .waves {
    height: 12px;
    min-height: 12px;
  }
  .content {
    height: 30vh;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
<div>
  <svg class="waves" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 24 150 28" preserveAspectRatio="none" shape-rendering="auto"> 
    <defs>
      <path id="gentle-wave" d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z" />
    </defs>
  <g class="parallax">
    <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="0" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.7" />
    <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="3" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" />
    <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="5" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)" />
    <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="7" fill="#fff" />
  </g>
</svg>
</div>



